# Is there a Library for dealing with OpenSoundControl in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, air, osc

I would like to send and receive OpenSoundControl in an AIR application, on the opensoundcontrol.org website I have found existing libraries for many languages, but none for Action Script so far, do you know of one that could be readily used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuio AS3 has nice classes for OSC. Check this example http://bubblebird.at/tuioflash/guides/sending-osc/